# Can I use different datasets according to the selected parameters using SSRS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

It's the first time that I am using SQL Server reporting services. I have two date type parameters: Start Date & End Date. I can run the report correctly when I fill these two parameters with the corresponding dataset.

However, when the user fills only the Start Date, I would like to show a report from that date and later. e.g. If the user fills only the Start Date my query will be something like that

```
WHERE StartDate >= @StartDate
```

or if the user fills only the EndDate field, my query will be something like that

```
WHERE EndDate <= @EndDate.
```

I have the following two questions:

1) Can I use different datasets according to what the user selects using SSRS? e.g if the user do not select anything I would like to run a different query.

2) and if yes how can I handle that ? because filter parameters are mandatory fields and all the time I receive the warning message.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a simpler solution to your problem, if I've understood things correctly. You seem to indicate the parameters are optional. In that case, just *Allow Null Values* for the parameter, and rewrite your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
WHERE (@StartDate IS NULL OR StartDate >= @StartDate)
AND   (@EndDate   IS NULL OR EndDate   <= @EndDate)
```

In any case, you can't "not execute a dataset" based on the chosen parameters (nor should you usually need to). If you do need something like that, a subreport is probably the way to go. However, based on your question I'd think there's a simpler solution available.

Comment: hmmm interesting answer, thank you for your reply Jeroen. I will check it and I will let you know.